# Iterate over vertices of CGAL polygon and get int coordinates

Tags: c++, iterator, cgal, vertex

My first problem is, that vertex iterators and points are "unknown" in CLION.
When I declare a point and want to access its member functions, there is no auto completion (unlike polygons, etc.).

My second question is, how can I iterate over the vertices of a polygon and get the coordinates of the vertices as int values?

The idea was as follows, but the return type of p.x() isn't an int or a double.

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_2.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef Kernel::Point_2 Point;
typedef CGAL::Polygon_2<Kernel> Polygon_2;

int main() {
    std::vector<Point> points;

    points.emplace_back(Point(10, 10));
    points.emplace_back(Point(20, 10));
    points.emplace_back(Point(20, 20));
    points.emplace_back(Point(10, 20));

    Polygon_2 poly(points.begin(), points.end());

    for (auto vi = poly.vertices_begin(); vi != poly.vertices_end(); ++vi)
    {
        int x = (*vi).x();
        int y = (*vi).y();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compiler Error:

```
main.cpp:20:13: error: no viable conversion from 'typename cpp11::result_of<typename R::Compute_x_2 (Point_2<Epeck>)>::type' (aka 'Lazy_exact_nt<CGAL::Gmpq>') to 'int'
    int x = (*vi).x();
        ^   ~~~~~~~~~
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

You might write `int x = CGAL::to_double((*vi).x());`
Then you get still a conversion warning. Do you intentionally use  `CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel` ?

Comment: No, I took it only from a CGAL example. Is there a better alternative?

Comment: @Yannic Please look at more cgal example. Find the one that uses ...inexact... kernel. usually if one is dealing with decimal based double/float co-ordinates, one would use ..inexact....